# Best current practice on versioning Yocto layer set

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

Yocto has a set of independent repositories containing the base system ([Poky](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/)) and various software components (all the [meta-* repositories here](https://git.yoctoproject.org/), and also [openembedded layer index](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/)). So when you want to build an image for specific device and purpose, you need a handful of repositories checked out.

These are all tied together by the `conf/bblayers.conf` and `conf/local.conf` files in the `build` directory. But that is a build directory—it is supposed to be disposable, containing only information that can be easily regenerated on request. And it does—except for the list of layers in `conf/bblayers.conf` and a couple of definitions like the `MACHINE` in the `conf/local.conf` that define the target system to build for.

How should I version this information?

Currently we have a rather hacky script that assembles the build directory and writes the config files, but it does not know how to properly update them when it changes.

So is there a better option? Preferably one that would avoid any additional steps between checkout/update (with submodules or `repo`), `oe-init-build-env` init script (which creates the build directory if it does not exist) and running `bitbake` with appropriate target image?

Comment: Is there anything (in YOCTO workflow) preventing `local.conf` and `bblayers.conf` from being symbolic links to elsewhere versioned files ? If not, you could have installation scripts generating symbolic links and calling `oe-init-build-env` for you

Comment: @YvesLhuillier, the problem is that *some* information in those configs is specific to the build environment and some is not.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `repo` is a convenient tool for managing manifest files with all the needed repositories.

Then you can use `TEMPLATECONF` to version `local.conf` and `bblayers.conf`. Here is how we do it: https://pelux.io/software-factory/master/chapters/baseplatform/building-PELUX-sources.html

Comment: Freescale community BSP uses repo as well, see [here](https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform)

Comment: `repo` is somewhat orthogonal to the question; the TEMPLATECONF part seems to be the best there is—with the problem that it does not support updating, but I don't see anything else that would.

Answer (score 0):

The Poky distribution itself uses the [Combo Layer](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Combo-layer) tool, which seems to be designed to address this particular problem. However, it's not very clear what the workflow is supposed to look like, when using this tool.

Regarding the default `bblayers.conf` and `local.conf` files, you can either version them anywhere in your project and have a script copy them in your build folder after calling `oe-init-build-env`, or simmply use `meta-poky/conf/bblayers.conf.sample` and `meta-poky/conf/local.conf.sample`, which are automatically installed by `oe-init-build-env` when first creating the build directory.

Now, when you make changes or add layers, you will have to clear the build directory for the changes in the `.sample` files to take effect.

Comment: It's not the same problem, because the problem I have applies even if I was building with just the poky repo alone. It still contains many layers that need to be activated or not and many configuration options and I need to version that set of options, in a consistent way.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is copying `oe-init-build-env` to project root directory, udpdating paths to correctly setup `OEROOT` and comenting out call to `"$OEROOT"/scripts/oe-setup-builddir`.

Project structure:

```
conf/
├─ local.conf
├─ bblayers.conf
layers/
├─ poky/
├─ foo/                  # custom layers
oe-init-build-env        # copied from layers/poky/oe-init-build-env
```

`conf` is checked into git repository,
layers inside `layers/` are added as submodules and its paths need to be set in `conf/bblayers.conf`

Modifications to [`oe-init-build-env`](https://github.com/yoctoproject/poky/blob/08369812c1a9a33338a3998968b802822b97c40a/oe-init-build-env):

```bash
if [ -z "$OEROOT" ]; then
    OEROOT=$(dirname "$THIS_SCRIPT")
    # OEROOT=$(readlink -f "$OEROOT")
    OEROOT=$(readlink -f "$OEROOT")/layers/poky. # this path updated
fi

# (...)

export OEROOT
. "$OEROOT"/scripts/oe-buildenv-internal 
# comment out call to oe-setup-builddir
#&&
#     TEMPLATECONF="$TEMPLATECONF" "$OEROOT"/scripts/oe-setup-builddir || {
#     unset OEROOT
#     return 1
# }
unset OEROOT

# (...)

# this is also not needed
#[ -z "$BUILDDIR" ] || cd "$BUILDDIR"
```

from now you can use bitbake from root of your project, and it will pick `conf/local.conf`